# How to update component from non-React environment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have most of my html code generated by server, but some things are much faster and easier to do in client with React so I need to create Component not in `#root`, but somewhere deep inside of my page. The nature of my application is that after the page is loaded it needs to retrieve data via API and it does it 5-6 times in a row with some small pause between each of requests. This normally takes from 10 to 30 seconds.

On the first request I can just check if element is not rendered yet and render it normally:

```
if('sorter' in window === false) {
    window.sorter = preactRender(<Sorter filterBoundaries={window.filters} />, document.querySelector('.sorter-holder'))
}
```

But then I need to send new props to `<Sorter />` in order to update it with newly arrived data. But how could I do it? I tried to do `window.sorter.forceUpdate()`, but it doesn't work because React's `render` method returns `Element`, which obviously doesn't have method `forceUpdate()`.

Maybe it would be a lot easier to remove old component and render it anew from the scratch? Even if it's anti-patern.

Comment: I suggest you to mount your `sorter` component on initial run. In the `Sorter` constructor assign `this` to some window variable say (`window.ins`). Then in your api call just call call `window.ins.setState` and the component would re-render smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I just sorted it out simply. I added to my application a global variable indicating if sorter needs and update:

```
if('sorter' in window === false) {
    window.sorter = preactRender(<Sorter filterBoundaries={window.filters} />, document.querySelector('.sorter-holder'))
} else {
    window.sorterUpdatePending = true
}
```

Then in my component I created an interval to check whether sorter update is pending or not. When it is - force an update and reset global variable. And when search is finished it clears the interval.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if(window.sorterUpdatePending === true) {
            this.forceUpdate()
            window.sorterUpdatePending = false
        }

        if(window.isSearching === false) {
            clearInterval(checkInterval)
        }
    }, 100)
}
```